# Protractor can't use local properties declared with this. inside .then statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, pageobjects

I've been trying to best organise my Protractor e2e tests in a reusable manner using the Page Object model. At the start of every Page Object I will define the elements on the page, followed by the local functions. e.g:

```
'use strict';

var examplePage = function() {
    // Locators
    this.button1   = $('#button1')
    this.element1  = $('#element1');
    this.element2  = $('.element2');

    // Error Messages
    this.ERROR_ONE = 'There was an error!';

    // Protractor ExpectedConditions instance
    var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    this.doSomeStuff = function() {
        this.button1.click().then(function() {
            browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(this.element1), global.TIMEOUT_INTERVAL_SHORT, this.ERROR_ONE);
            return this.element1;
        });
    };
};
module.exports = examplePage;
```

My code above is just an example. My real code is very similar.

Sometimes in my code I may need to control the order that the functions are executed to stop the functions from executing too early. However, this causes a completely local scope inside the .then statement. For example, the 'this.ERROR_ONE' property becomes inaccessible so I can't maintain my error messages and 'this.element1' becomes inaccessible.

Has anybody else encountered this and found a solution to this problem? It becomes messy to maintain the same value all over my Page Objects.

Comment: `this.something = whatever` doesn't declare a local variable. It doesn't declare a *variable* at all, it declares a *property* on whatever object `this` is. Anyway, to solve your problem, use the `.bind()` method, or keep a reference to `this` in an actual local variable (declared with `var`) within the `examplePage` function and then use *that* variable inside the `.then()`.

Comment: You spelt `'use strict'` as `'use struct'`

Comment: @nnnnn could you elaborate on an example of how I would achieve this? How could I pass that local variable to the code block inside the .then() statement? The anonymous function inside it seems to only receive the returned value from the resolved promise.

Comment: `var self = this` as the first line of `examplePage()`, and then inside the `.then()` just use `self.element1` and `self.ERROR_ONE`. Any *variable* declared in `examplePage()` is in scope in the nested function. [Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

Protractor team has a good [tutorial](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) on PageObject pattern for Protractor frameworks. You cannot use `this` to declare variables.

You can directly access the objects as shown in the above tutorial -

```
var examplePage = function() {
    // Locators
    var button1   = $('#button1');
    var element1  = $('#element1');
    var element2  = $('.element2');

    // Error Messages
    var ERROR_ONE = 'There was an error!';

    // Protractor ExpectedConditions instance
    var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    this.doSomeStuff = function() {
        this.button1.click().then(function() {
            browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(element1), global.TIMEOUT_INTERVAL_SHORT, ERROR_ONE);
            return element1;
        });
    };
};
module.exports = examplePage;
```

Comment: Declaring them as variables as opposed to properties unfortunately means that I need to specify setters and getters for each one. Some of my more complex pages have 30 or more elements that I need access to. I'm using the following style guide as it's a lot more comprehensive than the official Protractor wiki: https://github.com/CarmenPopoviciu/protractor-styleguide